# Is it possible to gather user input with CRM 2013 Package Deployer?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Package deployer is a great tool (no doubt about it) but there are cases where gathering user information would be very helpful allowing us to apply some configuration grammatically, things that now are part of a manual post installation process.

The documentation mentions a [RootControlDispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.tooling.packagedeployment.crmpackageextentionbase.importextension.rootcontroldispatcher.aspx) :

> *This is a dispatcher interface utilized to allow your control to render its own UI during package deployment. You would utilize this interface to wrap any UI elements or commands. It is important to check this variable for null values before using it as it may or may not be set to a value.*

Would be this the way to go? That is pretty much what the documentation has to say about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done when you are deploying using the UI client.  However it will not work if you are deploying with powershell. Thats why you must check to make sure the RootControlDispatcher is not null.

You can see an example of this in the CCA sample package in the UII part of the CRM SDK. 
CCA uses a custom UI to capture information on the CSR security role for non-English languages.

if it cannot find the security role it pops a dialog and asks the user for the role.
The way it does it is as follows:

```
RootControlDispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    // Load all Roles and asks the user to choose. 
    SecurityRoleSelector selFrm = new SecurityRoleSelector();
    if (selFrm.RolesDataModel != null)
    {
        selFrm.RolesDataModel.items.Clear();
        // Get the items for the control. 
        SearchFilter.Clear();
        var sL = rslts.Values.OrderBy(w => CrmSvc.GetDataByKeyFromResultsSet<string>(w, "name"));
        foreach (var rol in sL)
        {
            selFrm.RolesDataModel.items.Add(new CrmSecurityRoles()
            {
                RoleId = CrmSvc.GetDataByKeyFromResultsSet<Guid>(rol, "roleid"),
                RoleName = CrmSvc.GetDataByKeyFromResultsSet<string>(rol, "name")
            });
        }
        if (selFrm.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault(false))
        {
            // user selected an item. 
            if (selFrm.RolesControl.cbSelectedItem.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                CrmSecurityRoles role = (CrmSecurityRoles)selFrm.RolesControl.cbSelectedItem.SelectedItem;
                guCSRManagerRoleId = role.RoleId;
            }
        }
    }
    selFrm.Close(); // Clean up form. 
}), DispatcherPriority.Normal , null);
```

The securityroleselector form is a simple dialog with a drop down list.

Once it has the data, it is used to update the correct security role using logic like this:

```
if (guCSRManagerRoleId == Guid.Empty)
{
    // Error Something wrong here.. 
    RaiseUpdateEvent(CCADemoExtension.Resources.LocalResourcesCCADemoExt.RAISEUPDATEVENT_COULDNOTFIND_CSRMGRROLEINCRM_MSG, ProgressPanelItemStatus.Failed);
    PackageLog.Log("Could not find CSR Manager Role in CRM", System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Error);
    PackageLog.Log("RunUiiSpecificChanges", System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Stop);
    return false;
}
// Check to see if they are already associated... 
if (!IsRoleAssoicatedWithTeam(EscalationTeamId, guCSRManagerRoleId))
{
    // Try to assign team. 
    CrmSvc.CreateEntityAssociation("team", guTeamId, "role", guCSRManagerRoleId, "teamroles_association");
}
```

Hope that helps.